# .net connect to SQL Server database

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I have set up ASP.NET MVC on my local PC. I've set up a database in SQL Server Management Studio, and set the connection string in `web.config`. When I go to Server Explorer in VS2015 I can see the DB in my Data Connections. However, if I fire up the site and try and register a user I get the following error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

I know that the string is correct because I can see it in the Data Connections in VS2015

My `web.config` is as follows:

```
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory 
            type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory,
 EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
        <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
                  type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices,
 EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>   
</entityFramework>   
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ForexRebatesNowDBEntities" 
         connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.ForexRebatesNowEntities.csdl|res://*/Models.ForexRebatesNowEntities.ssdl|res://*/Models.ForexRebatesNowEntities.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider
 connection string=&quot;data source=MSIBEEDGE;initial
 catalog=ForexRebatesNowDB;persist security info=True;user
 id=sa;password=********;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;"
         providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />    
</connectionStrings>
```

This is frustrating the life out of me! I cannot understand how the App is not able to write to SQL Server

Comment: Try using the IP address of the SQL Server instead of the name. Your SQL Server has to be setup to allow remote connections as well.

Comment: Try connecting with SQL Server Management Studio from your local. That would be a good indication for you.

Comment: Compare the connection string from the server explorer to the one in your web.config and see what is different.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the SQL Server connection properties to verify connections are allowed?

The article below has steps to check for:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b43775b9-cd96-4f14-bd1e-b40172c5fc83/a-networkrelated-or-instancespecific-error-occurred-while-establishing-a-connection-to-sql-server?forum=sqlsecurity